# Spawning Enemies From ArrayList

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile, 2d-games

I have twelve enemies in an `ArrayList` and I want to delay the `batch.draw` for each enemy. I tried the following code in the `render` method but it just makes the sprites flicker. I am using `libgdx`. Please help ;(

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    fireDelay -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (fireDelay <= 0)
    {
        batch.draw(list.get(i)//..etc)                    
        fireDelay += 0.2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will definitely work:

```
boolean spawnTime=0;

void spawnEnemy(){
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
  rect.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2;
  rect.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
  rect.setSize(50,50);
  myList.add(rect);
}

spawnTime+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

//call spawnEnemy function every second
if(spawnTime>=1){
  spawnEnemy();
  spawnTime=0;
}

//draw all the rectangles to the batch you added in the list
for(Rectangle rect: myList){
  batch.draw(rect,rect.x,rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);
}
```

Note: Declare spawnTime globally.

Comment: `The following code will definitely work:` and if it does not you can always yell "it should have worked!"

Comment: If you want to avoid error building up, change the `if` to a `while` and change `spawnTime=0;` to `spawnTime-=1;`.

Comment: @Madmenyo We are programmers, thats what we do , right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in a game, your `render` method queues up all drawing commands. Then they are drawn to the screen. Then on the next call to `render()`, it clears the screen and starts over. Your code has a number of issues that don't make sense, like counting down the delta time inside a for loop.

There are a million ways to do this. Here's a simple one. What it does is on each call to `render()`, it updates the elapsed time and uses that to recalculate how many items should be showing now. Then the for loop draws all of them up to that number.

```
private static final float APPEARANCE_RATE = 5f; // 5 per second
private float elapsedTime = 0;

// in render():

elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

int itemCount = Math.min(list.size(), (int)(elapsedTime * APPEARANCE_RATE));
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    batch.draw(list.get(i), /*..etc*/);
}
```

Comment: I tried to run this but I can not get it working. All of my enemies in the ArrayList have the same position/behavior but must be drawned in the order of their index. I want to wait a second, spawn enemy  1, wait a second, spawn enemy 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet code as I've written using ModelBatch but the method works on spriteBatch too.

```
private int idx = 1;
private float elapsedTime = 0;
private int everySec = 1;
private Array<ModelInstance> storedInstance = new Array<>(); //extra array added each model every second to render in model batch.
```

And in render( ) method

```
modelBatch.begin(cam);
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

int time = (int) Math.floor(elapsedTime);

if (idx <= instance.size) {

if (time == idx * everySec) {
     storedInstance.add(instance.get(idx - 1));
     idx++;
    }
}
modelBatch.render(storedInstance);
modelBatch.end();
```

The idx checks if all models have been rendered in every second respectively. If you want to change the time span of model appearance you should just alter "everySec" to for instance 5 for 5 seconds delay. Also "instance" is the list of my models to be rendered( in your case, the enemies).